# Use Array of struct in proto

Tags: go, struct, proto

I am not able to call a gRPC function due to type mismatch

my proto file :

```
message Analytics {
    fields ...
}


message AnalyticsSet {
    repeated Analytics analytics = 1;
}

service StatService {
    rpc MyMethod(AnalyticsSet) returns (<something>) {}
}
```

Now, I need to call "MyMethod"

My current code :

```
type Analytics struct {
    same fields as in proto : Analytics
}

analytics := make([]Analytics, 4)

// .. some modifications in analytics ...

_, err := c.MyMethod(context.Background(), analytics)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error: %s", err)
}
```

in Proto file "AnalyticsSet" is the array of "Analytics"
and in Go code "analytics" is an array of type "Analytics"
but this is not enough to call "MyMethod", and I am facing type mismatch..

How should I modify the go code ?

Comment: Are you using the proto generated golang struct in your code or your own struct that matches the names of the fields in the proto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the `Analytics` struct generated from the proto file -- you cannot use your own type.

You can generate the required Go code using `protoc` with your `.proto` file. Here is an example with gRPC generation options set as well:
.

```
$ protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative analytics.proto
```

Your proto file should have the `go_package` option set to describe the Go import path for that your generated proto code belongs to. You will also need to install the go / go-grpc generator utilities required by `protoc`:

```
$ go install google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@latest
$ go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc@latest
```

More details can be found in:

- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/gotutorial
- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated
- https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/